# Subtract same number for all SQL rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 I have a user table like the following:

```
Userid
Username 
UserBirthYear(int)
```

When a user registers to the page, she choses her birthyear. Former programmer (of course!) let the user chose the correct year, but the value which was inserted into the db was DateTime.Now...

Now I need to subtract and save to the database 15 years from each user in coloumn UserBirthYear. There is 500k users. How is this best achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like all the data is incorrect anyway - if it's all been set to DateTime.Now. Subtracting 15 years is not going to give you the users' correct BirthYears...?

Comment: The user can chose from a dropdownlist which was populated with DateTime.Now-15 years (to insure the users age). So when she chose 1997 from the dropdown, the value inserted the database was 2012. Subtacting the 15 years now must på correct, right?

Comment: Argh, my mistake. It wasn't Datetime.Now. It was DateTime.Now and then -1 in the forloop while adding to the dropdown. Sorry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update your_table
set UserBirthYear = UserBirthYear - 15
```

Answer (score 0):

if inserted value is datetime then

try this  `select dateadd(year,-15,UserBirthYear)`

eg:

```
select dateadd(year,-15,'06-27-2012')
```

answer will be `1997-06-27 00:00:00.000`