# PHP - subtracting database selected float value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem in my codes i have selected float value from database now i want to subtract that value and update subtracted values into database table
below my codes.

```
$AmountGiven = $_POST['AmountGiven'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","xxx");


$selectuser = "SELECT * FROM users where email='$email'";
if($resultuser = mysqli_query($conn, $selectuser)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultuser) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser)) {
            $uuser_id = $row['uid'];
            $selctAllAmounttoShow = "SELECT * FROM donate WHERE user_id = '$uuser_id'";
            if( $resultToShowAmount = mysqli_query($conn, $selctAllAmounttoShow)){
                if( mysqli_num_rows($resultToShowAmount) > 0 ){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultToShowAmount)) {
                        $AmountAllToShow = $row['amount']; // these are float values
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Login First";
    }
}
$updateAmount = "UPDATE donate SET amount = '$AmountAllToShow' - '$AmountGiven' WHERE user_id = '$uuser_id'";
$queryUpdateAmount = mysqli_query($conn,$updateAmount);
if($queryUpdateAmount){
    echo "ALL DONE";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

$AmountAllToShow this variable have both float values like 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6 = 2.1.

If I have 2.1 value from all rows then how can I subtract these value with 1 like 2.1 - 1 = 1.1 and this 1.1 value send to $row['amount'] and  $row['amount'] value look like 0.3, 0.7, 0.1 whatever send to database numbers between 1.1?

Please help someone thanks StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$diff = $AmountAllToShow - $AmountGiven;
$updateAmount = "UPDATE donate SET amount = '$diff' WHERE user_id = '$uuser_id'";
```

Comment: It is bad practice to answer with code that is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. At least mention it and suggest a solution. SQL injection is one of the most common vulnerabilities in code written by novices, and the sooner it is pointed out, the better. (I am aware that `$diff` is the result of a computation and `$uuser_id` comes from the database)

Comment: i have got value from 4.4 - 1 = -0.7 in all rows why?

Comment: sir if i have 4.4 rupees selected from all rows to donate and i iam donating 1 rupess so i have subtracted amount 3.4 rupess then how can i update all rows with money between 3.4 like 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4 please help me first divide 3.4 with loop and then update with rows

Comment: Maybe this post will help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224266/subtract-same-number-for-all-sql-rows-in-table